# URLLoader Event.Complete not firing

Tags: html, haxe, openfl, urlloader

I'm trying to load data from a simple php file. I'm getting an IOErrorEvent message that states: "Unable to make request (may be blocked due to cross-domain restrictions)" This works find in AS3, but I'm trying to get it to work in Haxe + OpenFL (targeting HTML5). The code successfully posts the score, but doesn't COMPLETE the load (throwing an IOErrorEvent).

```
import openfl.net.URLVariables;
import openfl.net.URLRequest;
import openfl.net.URLLoader;
import openfl.events.IOErrorEvent;
import openfl.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
import openfl.system.Security;

public function save() {
    Security.allowDomain("www.roomrecess.com");
    Security.allowDomain("roomrecess.com");

    var sender:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var myVar:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        myVar.score = score;
    var website:URLRequest = new    URLRequest("http://www.roomrecess.com/php/boomSave.php");
        website.data = myVar;           
        sender.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
        sender.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, IOEErrorHandler);
        sender.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, SecEvHandler);
        sender.load(website);
}
public function IOEErrorHandler (e:IOErrorEvent)
{
    ground[0].visible = false;
    scoreDisplay.text = e.text;
    scoreFormat.size = 10;
    scoreDisplay.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
}
public function SecEvHandler (e:SecurityErrorEvent)
{
    ground[4].visible = false;
}
public function loadComplete(e:Event) {

    Security.allowDomain("www.roomrecess.com");
    Security.allowDomain("roomrecess.com");

    background.visible = false;

    sender.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete); //changed from loader to sender to match save()

    outputTxt.text = e.target.data; 

    bytes = outputTxt.text;
    mystring = bytes.toString();

    stats = mystring.split(" ");  //changed from int array to string array

    standings(); 
    loadCompleteVar = true;
}
```